# Vinagre XML bookmark password

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, vinagre

We have a couple of machines that run on Ubuntu and have Remote Desktop Viewer (Vinagre) to connect to a Windows 2008 R2 server. I have edited the vinagre-bookmarks.xml file to add bookmarks. I wanted to know if it is possible to add the password so that it may connect and logon automatically. I tried adding mypassword after username, but it didn’t work.